# Как преобразовать обратную польскую запись в обычную?

Tags: java, алгоритм, польская-запись

На входе - обратная польская запись формулы(String). Нужно перевести ее в обычную.
Пример:
Получаем:

```
2 3 + 6 2 / 5 2 * - +
```

Обрабатываем, отдаем:

```
2+3+6/2-5*2
```

Comment: а как уже пробовали?

Comment: удобно такие вещи [с помощью стека распознавать](https://goo.gl/cJgohu). Ещё [пример: `eval_rpn()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/580412/23044), прямая запись [рекурсией наглядно парсится `pn_eval()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20249546/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю автор просит алгоритм. Я бы писал его следующим образом: 
1. Бьём строку на массив по пробелу. 
2. Делаем обход по массиву со следующим правилом: 
  а. Если попалось число то кладём его в стэк. 
  б. Если попалась операция то достаём из стэка нужное количество операндов. Для унарных 1, для бинарных 2. В случае с бинарной операцией очевидно что верхний элемент это второй операнд. Результат кладем в стэк. 
3. На выходе у нас стэк с одним элементом.
**Как будет работать на примере:** 
Берём первый элемент (2) - это число - кладем в стэк - текущий стэк: 2 
Второй элемент (3) - это число - кладем в стэк - текущий стэк: 3,2 
Третий элемент (+) - бинарная операция - достаём 3, потом 2, кладём обратно 2 + 3 - текущий стэк: 2+3 
Далее буду приводить состояние стэка: 
(6)  6,2+3 
(2)  2,6,2+3 
(/)  6/2,2+3
(5)  5,6/2,2+3
(2)  2,5,6/2,2+3
(*)  5*2,6/2,2+3
(-)  6/2 -5*2,2+3
(+)  2+3 + 6/2 - 5*2

```
String input="2 3 + 6 2 / 5 2 * - +";
Stack stack=new Stack();
for(String element:input.split[' ']){
if(*проверка является ли элемент числом*){
   stack.push(element);
}else if(*проверка является ли операция унарной*){
   String op1=stack.pop();
   stack.push(op1+element);
}else{
   String op2=stack.pop();
   String op1=stack.pop();
   stack.push(op1+element+op2);
}
}
String result=stack.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

*вот правильный ответ:*
Скобки незаменимы.
Попробуй это: 2 3 + 6 2 / 5 2 + - 

*((2+3)*((6/2)-(5+2))) == -20
Здесь можно проверить [7th](https://www.7th-stone.com) `Download` (может решить оба типа выражений).

`fromRPN( new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList( "2 3 + 6 2 / 5 2 + - *".split( " " ) ) ) );  // ((2+3)*((6/2)-(5+2)))`

```
public String fromRPN( ArrayList<String> rpn ) {
  for( int n = 0; rpn.size() > 1; n++ )
    switch( rpn.get( n ) ) {
    case "+":
    case "-":
    case "*":
    case "/":
      String s = new StringJoiner( "", "(", ")" ).add( rpn.remove( n - 2 ) ).add( rpn.remove( n - 1 ) ).add( rpn.remove( n - 2 ) ).toString();
      rpn.add( n - 2, s );
      if( rpn.size() > 1 )
        return( fromRPN( rpn ) );
      return( rpn.get( 0 ) );
    case "sqrt":  // insert Your unary operator(s) here…
      StringJoiner join = rpn.get( n ).startsWith( "(" ) ? new StringJoiner( "" ) : new StringJoiner( "",  "(", ")" );
      join.add( rpn.remove( n ) );
      if( rpn.get( n - 1  ).startsWith( "(" ) )
        join.add( rpn.remove( n - 1 ) );
      else
        join.add( "(" ).add( rpn.remove( n - 1 ) ).add( ")" );
      s = join.toString();
      rpn.add( n - 1, s );
      if( rpn.size() > 1 )
        return( fromRPN( rpn ) );
      return( rpn.get( 0 ) );
    }
  return( fromRPN( rpn ) );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Логика такая, только тут задача решалась в лоб под конкретный пример, для более обширного решения нужно проводить проверку, т.е. символы строки сортировать по пробелам, мое решение будет применимо только к парам чисел, если будут стоять одиноко стоящие числа так не сработает, но это уже сам

```
 import com.sun.deploy.util.StringUtils;

import java.util.*;

public class hj{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = "2 3 + 6 2 / 5 2 * - +";
        String[] substring = value.split(" ");
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(substring));
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String>temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        int size = arrayList.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            if (i>0 &&i % 3 == 0)
                   list.add(0,arrayList.get(i-3)+arrayList.get(i-1)+arrayList.get(i-2));

        }
        int size1 = arrayList.size()-list.size()+1;
        size=arrayList.size()-size1;
        Collections.reverse(arrayList);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size()-size1; i++) {
            temp.add(arrayList.get(i));
        }
        Collections.reverse(temp);
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
            list.add(1+i*2,temp.get(i));
        }
        Collections.reverse(list);

        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Этот алгоритм будет работать не верно уже при таком случае 1 1 + 2 3 + 6 2 / 5 2 * - + +

Comment: [1+1, +, 2+3, +, 6/2, -, 5*2]

Comment: Накинь ещё операцию (1 1 +1 1 + 2 3 + 6 2 / 5 2 * - + + +) Или сделай только одну операцию (2 3 +)