# лексический анализатор и обратная полькая нотация для него

Tags: python, парсер

Я сделал токанайзер которое вот такое выражение `SET (3,4,5)` преобразует в `[('OP', 'SET'), ('LPAREN', '('), ('INT', '3'), ('DELIMARGS', ','), ('INT', '4'), ('DELIMARGS', ','), ('INT', '5'), ('RPAREN', ')')]`.

Хочу сделать функцию преобразования в "обратную польскую нотацию"-функцию opn().На выходе в листе `res` должно быть
[`'3','4','5','SET']`.

Я хочу использовать запятую т.е. разделитель аргументов `DELIMARGS`.В вики написано про ОПН:если токен-разделитель аргументов функцци(напр.
запятая):Пока токен на вершине стека не открывающая скобка,перекладывать операторы из стека в выходную очередь.Если в стеке не было
открывающей скобки,то в выражении пропущен разделитель аргументов функции,либо пропущена открывающая скобка.
Если токен -закрывающая скобка:пока токен на вершине стека не является открывающей скобкой,перекладывать операторы из стека в выходную 
очередь.Выкинуть открывающую скобку из стека,но не добавлять в выходную очередь.Не могу это полностью реализовать.
(Я делал отладку и подписывал некоторые текущие переменные)

```
op_stack=[]    
res=[] 
def opn(list_with_tuples_tokens):
    #list_with_tuples_tokens = [('OP', 'SET'), ('LPAREN', '('), ('INT', '3'), ('DELIMARGS', ','), ('INT', '4'), ('DELIMARGS', ','), ('INT', '5'), ('RPAREN', ')')]
    for chunk_tuple_with_tag_value in list_with_tuples_tokens:#chunk_tuple_with_tag_value=('OP', 'SET')

        if    (chunk_tuple_with_tag_value[0]=='INT' or chunk_tuple_with_tag_value[0]=='ID'):#esli token chislo | indificator -dobavit v ochered vivoda
             res.append(chunk_tuple_with_tag_value[1])#<---s_out=['3']
        elif  (chunk_tuple_with_tag_value[0])=='OP':#esli token funcsiya -pomestit v stek
             op_stack.append(chunk_tuple_with_tag_value[1])#<---#=['SET'] ->['SET', '(']
        elif  (chunk_tuple_with_tag_value[0])=='DELIMARGS':#esli token razdelitel argumentov funcsii
            if len(op_stack)!=0:
               token=op_stack.pop()
            while token!='(' :

                if token=='(':
                   break #<---

                token=op_stack.pop() 
                res.append(token)  




        elif   (chunk_tuple_with_tag_value[0])=='LPAREN':#esli token otkrivaushay skobka polojit v stek
             op_stack.append(chunk_tuple_with_tag_value[1])#<--- 
        elif   (chunk_tuple_with_tag_value[0])=='RPAREN':#esli token zakrivayushaya skobka

            if len(op_stack)!=0:
                token=op_stack.pop()
            while token!='(' and len(op_stack)!=0:


                if token=='(':
                    break #<---

                token=op_stack.pop() 
                res.append(token)                  




    while len(op_stack)!=0:
        token=op_stack.pop()
        if token=='(':
            break
        res.append(token)
opn([('OP', 'SET'), ('LPAREN', '('), ('INT', '3'), ('DELIMARGS', ','), ('INT', '4'), ('DELIMARGS', ','), ('INT', '5'), ('RPAREN', ')')])              
print(res)
print(op_stack)
```

Comment: [ссылки на несколько примеров кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711128/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E#comment1064067_711128)

Answer (score 0):

Кое что получается,я стал смотреть что на вершине оператора стека так
token_tmp=op_stack[len(op_stack)-1].Так лучше идет.

Привожу код с лексером:

```
#import pdb
#pdb.set_trace()

import re
def op_prior(char_op):
    if char_op=='*':
        return 5
    elif char_op=='/':
        return 4
    elif char_op=='%':
        return 3
    elif char_op=='+':
        return 2
    elif char_op=='-':
        return  1  

tokens=[]
keywords = {'IF', 'THEN', 'ENDIF', 'FOR', 'NEXT', 'GOSUB', 'RETURN','SET'}
def tokenize(s):


    token_specification = [
        ('INT',  r'\d+(\.\d*)?'), # Integer or decimal number
                 # Assignment operator
        ('END',     r';'),           # Statement terminator
        ('ID',      r'[A-Za-z]+'),   # Identifiers
        ('OP',      r'[+*\/%-]'),  # Arithmetic operators
        ('LPAREN',      r'\('),
        ('RPAREN',      r'\)'),
        ('DELIMARGS',      r','),
        ('NEWLINE', r'\n'),          # Line endings
        ('SKIP',    r'[ \t]'),       # Skip over spaces and tabs 

    ]
    tok_regex = '|'.join('(?P<%s>%s)' % pair for pair in token_specification)
    #tok_regex='(?P<NUMBER>\\d+(\\.\\d*)?)|(?P<ASSIGN>:=)|(?P<END>;)|(?P<ID>[A-Za-z]+)|(?P<OP>[+*\\/\\-])|(?P<NEWLINE>\\n)|(?P<SKIP>[ \\t])'
    get_token = re.compile(tok_regex).match
    line = 1
    pos = line_start = 0 #pos=0
    mo = get_token(s) #mo=<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='\n'>
    while mo is not None:#class True
        typ = mo.lastgroup #typ='NEWLINE'
        if typ == 'NEWLINE':
            line_start = pos#line_start=0
            line += 1# line=2
        elif typ != 'SKIP':
            val = mo.group(typ)
            token=(typ,val)
            if typ == 'ID' and val in keywords:
               typ = val
               token=(typ,val)
            tokens.append(token)
        pos = mo.end()#pos=1
        mo = get_token(s, pos)#mo=<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 2), match=' '>
    if pos != len(s):
        raise RuntimeError('Unexpected character %r on line %d' %(s[pos], line))

statements = '''

     ( 5 + 100)*3


'''

tokenize(statements)
print(tokens)

op_stack=[]    
res=[] 
def opn(list_with_tuples_tokens):
   #list_with_tuples_tokens = [('LPAREN', '('), ('INT', '5'), ('OP', '+'), ('INT', '100'), ('RPAREN', ')'), ('OP', '*'), ('INT', '3')]
    for chunk_tuple_with_tag_value in list_with_tuples_tokens:#chunk_tuple_with_tag_value=('OP', 'SET')

        if    (chunk_tuple_with_tag_value[0]=='INT' or chunk_tuple_with_tag_value[0]=='ID'):#esli token chislo | indificator -dobavit v ochered vivoda
             res.append(chunk_tuple_with_tag_value[1])#<---res=['5']
        elif  (chunk_tuple_with_tag_value[0])=='OP':#esli token funcsiya -pomestit v stek chunk_tuple_with_tag_value=('OP', '+')->('OP', '*')
           if len(op_stack)!=0: #op_stack=['(']
            token_tmp=op_stack[len(op_stack)-1] #token_tmp='('
           while(len(op_stack)>=0):
               if(token_tmp in ['*','/','%','+','-' ] and op_prior(chunk_tuple_with_tag_value[1])<=op_prior(token_tmp)):
                   res.append(op_stack.pop())
               op_stack.append(chunk_tuple_with_tag_value[1])#op_stack=['(', '+']
               break

        elif  (chunk_tuple_with_tag_value[0])=='DELIMARGS':#esli token razdelitel argumentov funcsii
            token_tmp=op_stack[len(op_stack)-1]
            while(token_tmp!='('):
                res.append(op_stack.pop())
                if len(op_stack)==0 and token_tmp!='(':
                    raise RuntimeError("Net levoi skobki")                
                token_tmp=op_stack[len(op_stack)-1] 





        elif   (chunk_tuple_with_tag_value[0])=='LPAREN':#esli token otkrivaushay skobka polojit v stek
             op_stack.append(chunk_tuple_with_tag_value[1])#<--- op_stack=['(']
        elif   (chunk_tuple_with_tag_value[0])=='RPAREN':#esli token zakrivayushaya skobka
            token_tmp=op_stack[len(op_stack)-1]#token_tmp='+'
            while(token_tmp!='('):
                res.append(op_stack.pop())
                token_tmp=op_stack[len(op_stack)-1]
                if token_tmp=='(':
                    op_stack.pop()                






    while len(op_stack)!=0:
        token_tmp=op_stack[len(op_stack)-1]
        if token_tmp=='(':
           raise RuntimeError("V virajenii net pravoi skobki")
        res.append(op_stack.pop())                       
opn(tokens)              
print(res)
print(op_stack)
```